# В чем смысл использования пула DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

В чем смысл использования пула контекстов, если подключение он все равно не сохраняет, а инициализация контекста может быть вынесена, чтобы не делалась каждый раз в самом контексте - тем самым сделав создание контекста дешевым.

Вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#dbcontext-pooling) написано:

> Как DbContextправило, это легкий объект: его создание и удаление не требует операций с базой данных, и большинство приложений могут выполнять это без какого-либо заметного влияния на производительность. Однако каждый экземпляр контекста устанавливает различные внутренние службы и объекты, необходимые для выполнения его обязанностей, и накладные расходы на постоянное выполнение этого могут быть значительными в высокопроизводительных сценариях

Но я ведь могу просто сделать services.AddDbContext<> и получить по-идее точно такой же результат. Так зачем мне пул?

Comment: В целом это описано в доке майкрософта - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#dbcontext-pooling

поясняют что есть внутренние сервисы в DbContext которые в perf-critical приложениях может дать доп. буст. при пуллинге. Естественно надо сперва бенчмаркать приложение и регрессить и смотреть даёт это профит или нет.

Comment: @Vein В каком месте создание DbContext является тяжелой операцией, что "только пул может помочь"? Это слишком абстрактное объяснение как и в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444206/17025310) ответе. `Pooling has some performance gains` - слишком жидко и ни о чем. Разве пул сущестует только ради perf-critical приложений?

Comment: я даже больше скажу, любой пул, будь то пул контеекстов, соединений, потоков или чего еще существует в основном для повышения производительности

Comment: Создание контекста хоть и дёшево, но всё же не бесплатно. Взять готовый контекст из пула быстрее, чем создать новый с нуля.

Comment: _я ведь могу просто сделать services.AddDbContext<>_ - при этом будет создаваться _новый_ контекст каждый раз при инъекции (в зависимости от скоупа).

Comment: _Разве пул сущестует только ради perf-critical приложений?_ - Да.